# Can't register for addons or plugins

Tags: plugins

I have Gimp 2.6
I would like to add plugins to my program.
I went to Gimp Plugin Registry.
I entered all the information requested.

I spent at least half an hour of frustration trying to persuade the website to accept my email address. No matter what I do, I'm told that my email address is invalid.

More frustration: The page tells me to contact Gimp for help. There's no provision (that I can see) to make contact.

I'm at a complete standstill and am hoping you can point me in the right direction.

Liam Kincaid

Comment: I have downloaded a few and didn't needed to register

Answer (score 0):

#### A repository of extensions for GIMP, the FREE and Open Source image manipulation program.

[image]

This is the statement from the web site:

"If you'd like to upload plug-ins, please create an account below. You do not need one for download. Enjoy :-)"

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot. I humbly thank you, and quietly slink away.